# MS-SQL 2012 Principle "Freeze"

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, database-mirroring

yesterday I had a "freeze" of one of our customers mirrored database.

The symptom was that all applications freezed.
There was no high cpu (~1% for the sql server and ~10% total) / memory (4GB free ) / disk (50GB free) utilisation.

I tried accessing the principle-database with the Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio. When I tried to open the Tables section the application freezed as well.

I then stopped the whole server and the applications switched automatically to the mirror-database and continued as if nothing happened.

After (re)starting the stopped sql-server I could resume the mirroring without any problem.

I tried to find some information in the windows events, but except for the messages that I stopped the server and the resulting messages that the mirror became principle, there was no failure event.

Also our applications that access the database did not report any issues.

As an additional information (I don't know if it's of any importance): We have got a job running that backups the database with a full backup every hour and with a differential backup every 15 minutes (The diff backups go into the bak file created by the full backup).
The backup files get overwritten after one week. They are stored on the witness-server

Questions:
Is there anywhere else I might find some information about what has happened?
Has anyone of you experienced something similar?

Thank you for any suggestion.

UPDATE:
Today we had another problem with the database mirroring. But this time I could still query the database with the SSMS. The only thing was that none of my applications could query the database. But they didn't give any exception either.
They started working immediately when I pressed the pause button on the mirror-settings page. So I don't think it's a query-deadlock that causes the problem as Jeroen Mostert mentioned. Otherwise it wouldn't have helped pausing the mirror.

Has anyone another suggestion what might be the problem?

UPDATE:
Today I had another database freeze. I took the time to do what @Jeroen Mostert suggested.

I had six session_id that had a blocking_session_id. All blocking_session_id pointed to different session_id entries with the wait_type DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT and again a simple mirror.pause made the system responsive again.

Any help is appreciated.

Thomas

Comment: Well, you restarted, losing any way to diagnose the issue, but the most likely explanation is that there was a lock on the database or some system table preventing any transaction from proceeding. Querying `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` would tell you more about that.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: It's hard to do "nothing" when production stands still at the customer... But shouldn't that result in timeouts on the other waiting queries?

Comment: I'm not saying you shouldn't have restarted, just that after-the-fact investigation is likely impossible. And what locks result in timeouts on what queries depend on exactly what locks they are. But "everything I do seems to hang" is a classic symptom of a transaction in progress holding a lock somewhere. (`DBCC OPENTRAN` is another good one to have in the arsenal, a judicious `KILL` can do wonders.)

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert: OK, thank you. As it is likely to happen again if it happened once, I will try your suggestion then. I just hope it doesn't happen at night :-/

Comment: Your assertion that it is not a locking issue 'because pausing mirroring solved it' is incorrect. Locking can be caused when for instance the application is attempting to read from the table, while the mirroring process started a transaction attempting to read the same table. I think Jeroen is actually spot on with his assessment. Look into `sys.dm_os_wait_stats` to determine what waits are occurring on your server when the problem occurs. Hopefully that gives you some more insight into what's going on.

Comment: @SchmitzIT: Thats what I did, but there are no circular dependencies visible if I look at the columns session_id and blocking_session_id. How else can I see a deadlock?

Comment: @ThomasVoß - sp_who2 usually will give you a clue about which processes are blocking/being blocked

Comment: @SchmitzIT: The sp_who gives me two session_id. One has an UPDATE cmd and the other is in COMMIT TRANSACTI cmd. Both of those sessions have the wait_type DBMIRROR_DBM_EVENT. All other sessions have a SELECT cmd.

Comment: @ThomasVoß The output of sp_who2 has a column called BlkBy. That should be empty. If it's not, something is blocking the process. It will contain a numeric value in that case, which itself is a SPID you can use to identify what process is the culprit.